# Generating Google map markers via iterating over an array using data-binding, Why am I losing my infowindow and/or click events on data update?

Tags: google-maps, polymer, google-maps-markers, web-component, google-web-component

Using google-map v1.1.10 against git://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map.git#*

I build up my markers like so:

```
<template>
   <site-data sites="{{sites}}"> </site-data>
   <google-map fit-to-markers >
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sites}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item}}">
      <google-map-marker latitude={{item.latitude}}
                         longitude={{item.longitude}}
                         title="{{item.project_name}}"
                         >
        <h1>{{item.project_name}}</h1>
        <p style="margin: 0;">Location: <b>{{item.town}}, {{item.country}}</b></p>
        <p style="margin: 0;">Tech Description: <b>{{item.tech_desc}}</b></p>
      </google-map-marker>
    </template>
  </template>
</google-map>
```

Upon initial loading of the webapp, things work really well. I can click on a marker and the infowindow shows the content. However, if I change any values in my sites array, I seem to lose the infowindow and/or the click event. I have to refresh the browser to get back to my initial condition (click to show infowindow).

Also, The marker locations will update perfectly if I change lat/long and hovering shows tooltip aka. title, appropriately as well.

I've added a click event which calls a console.log to the click event. It works well until a value is changed in the {{sites}} binding, so it seem I am losing click events when the google-map updates itself?

There are no scripts in this element.

If I can provide more information, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some problems with GoogleMapMarker. I have some hacks you can try, but you should make an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues) ticket so somebody can take a deeper look.

One problem is that the MutationObserver that updates MapMarker is not observing `characterData`, so it doesn't fire when MapMarker's simple text content changes.

Another problem is that the `attach`/`detach` implementations don't seem to be complementary. For example, `detach` removes the MutationObserver and `attach` never puts it back.

Lastly, there are cases when the `info` window become disconnected from the MapMarker.

Here is a JSBin where there are three kinds of mutations of a GoogleMapMarker setup as you described: http://jsbin.com/hobixi/edit?html.

- Adding a new map marker seems to work just fine.
- Modifying content of an existing marker fails because of the MutationObserver problem I described. I fixed that by monkey patching GoogleMapMarker's `_contentChanged` method like so:

Example:

```
marker._contentChanged = function() {
  if (this._contentObserver)
    this._contentObserver.disconnect();
    // Watch for future updates.
    this._contentObserver = new MutationObserver( this._contentChanged.bind(this));
    this._contentObserver.observe( this, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      ///----------------
      // monkey patch 
      characterData: true
      //-----------------
    });
 ...
```

- Lastly, I artificially made an example that removes a marker from DOM and puts it back. This fails as described above, so I monkey patched `attached` and `detached` like so:

Example:

```
  marker.detached = function() {
    if (this.marker) {
      google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.marker);
      this._listeners = {};
      this.marker.setMap(null);
      ///----------------
      // monkey patch 
      this.info = null;
      //-----------------
    }
    if (this._contentObserver)
      this._contentObserver.disconnect();
  };
  marker.attached = function() {
    // If element is added back to DOM, put it back on the map.
    if (this.marker) {
      this.marker.setMap(this.map);
      ///----------------
      // monkey patch 
      this._contentChanged();
      //-----------------
    }
  };
```

You didn't specify the nature of the changes you are triggering. The `clicking doesn't show the info window` problem seems to be what happens when the Marker and the Info become discombobulated, maybe there is an `attach/detach` happening.

Well played baiting me to look into this. :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have filed a report here:https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/257 Would you mind if I added your feedback to that issue? In the meantime I will use your work-around, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure, link it to this SO post, that was what I was thinking.